# Prefix 0 to numbers 0-9

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 0 to number 0-9 which I was able to do. Now the end result needs to look like `'w01_Hello_World'` and increment by 1. I'm having trouble adding the result between `w` and `_`.

```
const pad = (n) => (latest < 10) ? ('0' + n) : n;

const result = `w${result goes here + 1}_Hello_World`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to generate a string that includes a number which got incremented and has a leading zero.

```js
let latest = 5; // Your number
const pad = n => n < 10 ? ('0' + n) : n;
const result = `w${pad(latest+1)}_Hello_World`;
    
console.log(latest); // Should print: 5
console.log(result);  // Should print: w06_Hello_World
```

Comment: This works! I didn't think of adding + 1 in the pad arguments. Thanks

Comment: Hey Jaime O, i'm glad that your problem got solved and your code is now working. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I clicked the up arrow but I don't have sufficient rep point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
const pad = (n) => (n < 10) ? ('0' + n) : n;

const result = `w${pad(7)}_Hello_World`;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing `n` to integer before comparing. The best way to parse a variable into a number is the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) (+), so you can try this:

```js
const pad = (n) => (+n < 10) ? ('0' + n) : n;

[1,15,9,28,3,9,0,09].forEach((e)=>console.log(`Number: ${pad(e)}`));
```

This validates that `n` is not longer than two digits even if it is smaller than 10.